# How to connect to a MySql-Server in the internet from MySql Workbench?

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

Is it possible to connect to a server in the internet from mysql workbench?

Comment: Yes.  Are you running into a particular problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long the server on the internet has a mysql port open (normally 3306) you should be able to connect via Workbench - Use Tools>Manage Connections to set up the details